# why always popup a info that the key cannot be empty when I insert a row into cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I was able to install the GUI tools called "Cassandra-Cluster-Admin-master" on the windows.

Before I install the GUI, I create the column family with following code:

```
create column family user with comparator=UTF8Type
and column_type = Standard
and default_validation_class=UTF8Type and key_validation_class=UUIDType
and column_metadata=
[
{column_name: username, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS},
{column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type},
{column_name: userBrief, validation_class: UTF8Type},
{column_name: jobNumber, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}
];
```

And here is the picture from the GUI on the basic info of the user columnfamily.
[image: index in the user]

But when I want to edit specific row,
there is some error info like this:
[image: error info]
But the key is displayed here.
I do not understand the difference between the key and rowKey.
Is there anyone face the same problem?
Any feedback will be appricated.

Comment: It's probably because your web interface does not pass the key UUID to the back-end, or there is some bug in the back-end. Just try to run in debug mode and check whether the key UUID is passed correctly to the DAO layer